# How do I select data to the end of the line using RegEx?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following data line: 
`oauthscope: command_path.use`

Trying to create a RegEx expression that will retrieve just `command_path.use`

I've tried this, but it's selecting the opposite of what I want:

```
^oauthscope: (.*?)
```

My java code looks like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^oauthscope: (.*?)");
String mydata = "oauthscope: command_path.use";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
if(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("I found: '" + matcher.group(1) + "'");
} else {
    System.out.println("No match found!");
}
```

The result I get is this:
`I found: ''` - I don't know how to tell it to fetch everything starting with that pattern to the end of the line.

Comment: Use `.*` to match any 0+ chars rather than a reluctant `.*?`. At the end of a pattern, `*?` quantified patterns never match any char, they do not have to consume chars.

Comment: It worked, but I don't understand why...  Is removing the ? causing it to be more greedy in its matching?

Comment: It just makes it try at least once. `.*?` does not trigger at all, it is only triggered when the *subsequent* subpatterns do not match.